# Different layout for just one certain page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a different layout for just one certain action in my Rails app. How do I do that?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails 3, how add a view that does not use same layout as rest of app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090084/rails-3-how-add-a-view-that-does-not-use-same-layout-as-rest-of-app)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 layout :resolve_layout

  .
  .
  .
     private   
      def resolve_layout
       case action_name
         when "new"
          "alternate"
         else 
          "application"
         end
      end
```

Answer (score 27):

```
# controller that calls the page
def action
  render :layout => 'other'
end
```

Comment: So in my case, my "def action" is "def homepage" AKA the index. I made a layout.css.scss file and placed it in my stylesheets folder and added in your render line with 'other' being 'layout' and my application crashed. I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong. My new layout file is the same as my original layout file.

Comment: Hard to say without checking the code, open a new question and I can have a look

Answer (score 19):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout "special", :only => :action

  def action
    #action code
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm. Actually, that makes all my other actions for that controller have NO layout. Any way to bring those back?

Comment: I haven't tried, but what about put another line on top for default? something like `layout 'normal' # :except => :action`

Comment: @ecologic, that won't work (in rails 3.0.X anyway).  You can only have global one layout declaration per controller