# Different view-options in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best practise for creating a view page in Rails with different view-options, such as a basic view with mostly text and an advanced view with graphical features? More specifically, I would like to have a view page where the the user can toggle between a basic/advanced show view. Clicking the toggle button renders one set of divs corresponding to selected view. Should this be done though a form_for/if-else statement in html markup or is it better do to do it in javascript? I guess turning the `<div id="id">` on/off could be done in javascript through:

```
$("#id").show()
$("#id").hide()
```

I have a problem understanding how a rails implementation is done, where do I put the if-else statement (i.e. if user basic view is toggled render `<div id="basic">`, else `<div id="advanced">`)?

```
<%= form_for ??? do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit ??? %>           
<% end %>
```

**Edit 2:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="btn-group" id="basic-advanced" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <a class="btn btn-small" href="#" id="basicbutton">Basic</a>
        <a class="btn btn-small" href="#" id="advancedbutton">Advanced</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="basic">
  This is the basic view
</div>

<div class="container" id="advanced">
  This is the advanced view
</div>
```

Now in javascript I have the following:

```
$("#basic").toggle();
$("#basic-advanced").click(function (){
  $("#basic").toggle();
  $("#advanced").toggle();
});
```

I have added the above code, but how do I keep track of which viewing mode that the page is in? From the answers it seems like one could set an instance variable, @viewing_mode, to a value corresponding to the mode, but how should this be done? Through a form?

**Update**: I managed to achieve a toggle using a session variable, and an if/else statement, the procedure is described here: [Session variable not persisting after switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740313/session-variable-not-persisting-after-switch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `jQuery.show()` and `jQuery.hide()` that means you need both the basic and advanced div tags rendered. Rails needs to render them both. You can just have toggle  `display:hidden` css, here I did that with variable `@use_advanced`.

```
<div id="advanced" <%= (@use_advanced) ? '' : ' style="display:hidden"' %>>...

<div id="basic" <%= (@use_advanced) ? ' style="display:hidden"' : '' %>>...
```

To toggle between the two you could have a button: `<button>toggle</button>`

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('#advanced').toggle();
  $('#basic').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Ok, so you mean that it would waste resources? How do I couple the display:hidden to a toggle button?

Comment: @graphmeter what do you mean waste resources?

Comment: thought you meant that the hide/show approach would require  rails to perform more work to render all divs, then jQuery would show/hide them, but maybe I completely misunderstood it.

Comment: rails does have to render all divs, more work as compared to what?

Comment: Thanks. Ok. Sorry for the confusion, thought the javascript was executed after the html is processed, so that if you had an if-else statement in erb in the html code it would not process the code further down.

Answer (score 1):

There are some different cases:

1) if you are able to change your view using `CSS` only - then you should enclose all the page inside classified div:

```
<div class='my-style'>
  ...
</div>
```

2) if first solution is not applicable then you may use if-else statement:

```
<% if @my_style_selected %>
  <div>My style</div>
<% else %>
  <div>Default</div>
<% end %>
```

3) finally, if neither solution suits you. You may write some `JS` to dynamically replace your `divs`. The best solution is to replace some parts of the page using `AJAX`. If you will render both variants and hide one of them - that will almost double your page load time.

Comment: Thanks. In the 2) how do I set @my_style_selected from a toggle button?

Comment: In scope 2) it may be done only via page reload. You may send selected style and rerender another conditional branch.

Answer (score 1):

Given that yiou are using rails I would look into using layout for different views rather than having conditional logic.

For more info see [rails 3, how add a view that does not use same layout as rest of app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5090084/631619)

Comment: this doesn't address his toggle requirement

Comment: Thanks. Using the referenced approach I guess I would have to have two different .html files?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JavaScript object (written in CoffeScript) that will allow you to switch between as many modes as you like using a convention:

```
class ModeSwitcher
  constructor: ($area, modes) ->
    $area = $ $area
    me = this

    bindToggle = (mode) ->
      $area.find('a.toggle.' + mode).click ->
        me.toggle mode

    $ ->
      bindToggle(mode) for mode in modes

  toggle: (mode) ->
    $('.mode').hide()
    $('.' + mode + '.mode').show()
```

Here's an example of how you could construct the object (JavaScript/jQuery):

```
  var switcher = new ModeSwitcher('body', ['basic', 'advanced']);
  $(function() {
    switcher.switch("<%= @mode %>");
  });
```

The `@mode` instance variable is set in the Rails controller and says which mode the view should start out in:

`@mode = params[:mode] || 'basic'`

As for how it works by convention, you would have sections like this:

```
<div class="basic mode">...</div>
<div class="advanced mode">...</div>
```

And you would have links like this:

```
<a class="toggle advanced">Switch to advanced mode</a>
<a class="toggle basic">Switch to basic mode</a>
```

When constructed, the object will iterate through all the declared modes and look for the toggle links. It will then bind the toggling function to those links.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I dont know coffeescript...but I guess the javascript code is similar. How do you choose which dom objects that should toggle basic or advanced?

Comment: How would you set/define the instance variable @mode in the controller?

Comment: Take another look, all is explained above. Anything wrapped in `<div class="basic mode"></div>` will be shown when the `<a class="toggle basic"></a>` link is clicked. In fact, *any* element with a class of `basic mode` will be toggled, not just a `div`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I set `@mode` in the controller. This way, you can add a `mode=basic` or `mode=advanced` url parameter when you request the page and it will render in your desired mode.

Comment: great, I tried to add an instance variable to a method in the controller: `def prepare_for_viewing, @mode = params[:mode] || "0", end`, with a simple if-else statement in the show view setting :mode to 0 or 1...but the instance variable doesn't seem to persist?

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. Instance variables should always be available in your view. In your `show` action, make sure you're calling `prepare_for_viewing`, and try adding `?mode=foo` to your URL. Then print the value of `@mode` on your page somehow or do a JavaScript alert.