# Session variable not persisting after switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried to implement a switch between a basic and advanced viewing mode on a show page, essentially switching a basic/advanced div on/off through a link. In the controller I store the viewing-mode in a session variable (using a similar approach to http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices). Problem: the toggling works fine changing the viewing mode, but as soon as I click on a link to a different show-page in the non-default viewing-mode it takes me back to the default-mode, why is this?

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if viewing_mode? %>
    <%= link_to "Advanced", {mode: 0}  %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Basic", {mode: 1} %>
<% end %>

<% if viewing_mode? %>
  <div class="container" id="basic">
   This is the basic view
  </div>

<% else %>
  <div class="container" id="advanced">
  This is the advanced view
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
before_filter :prepare_for_viewing

def viewing_mode?
  if session[:viewing_param]
    session[:viewing_param] == "1"
  else
    session[:viewing_param] == "0"
  end
end
helper_method :viewing_mode?

def prepare_for_viewing
  session[:viewing_param] = params[:mode] if params[:mode]
end
```

**Edit 1**: Displaying the session parameters shows that the :viewing_params changes from:

```
"viewing_param"=>"1"
```

to

```
"viewing_param"=>"1.json"
```

after clicking on a link on a show page. This might be the problem, but why is the viewing_param modified in this way?

**Edit 2**: I got it to work after adding a hack, setting the "a.json" to "a", not a nice solution but it works:

```
def prepare_for_viewing
  session[:viewing_param] = params[:mode][0] if params[:mode]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This method seems to be incorrect? I made some comments

```
def viewing_mode?
  # this is true for all values except nil and false
  if session[:viewing_param]
    # should it be test here? Or setting a value?
    session[:viewing_param] == "1"
  else
    # can never be "0" here, because that value gives true in the test above
    session[:viewing_param] == "0"
  end
end
```

You are using this:

```
link_to "Advanced", {mode: 1}
```

for advanced link, and in this:

```
before_filter :prepare_for_viewing
def prepare_for_viewing
  session[:viewing_param] = params[:mode] if params[:mode]
end
```

You are setting `session[:viewing_param]` to `"1"` (when advanced), then in

```
def viewing_mode?
  if session[:viewing_param]
    session[:viewing_param] == "1"
  else
    session[:viewing_param] == "0"
  end
end
```

You are getting true, and that will give you "basic" view because of this:

```
<% if viewing_mode? %>
  <div class="container" id="basic">
   This is the basic view
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, my method is incorrect..what I would like is to set viewing_mode? to true/false when :mode is set to 0/1. It seems to be doing this, when i print out viewing_mode?

Comment: I'm not sure of how it works in the rest of your code, but as `viewing_mode?` is done now it will work anyway if you have either "1" or "2" in session[:viewing_param]. It will always go into `if session[:viewing_param]` but since you have `session[:viewing_param] == "1"` it will answer true when "1" and false for all other values. It works, but not so nice :)

Comment: I added some description in my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, I will try to make the code more straightforward :). It seems like the problem of the redirect is that ".json" is added to the :viewing_param when clicking on links? Any ideas to how this is possible? I respond_to .json in the show, but same thing after commenting out.

Comment: If you have changed any code after you made the question, please update the question. And perhaps you should add more code, e.g. from the controller.

Comment: It was the .json that was the problem, added a solution in the question. However, still don't know why it converts the session variable to json..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you're trying to do (depending on which mode is the default):

```
before_filter :prepare_for_viewing
helper_method :advanced_view_mode?, :basic_view_mode?

def advanced_view_mode?
  session[:viewing_param] == '1'
end

def basic_view_mode?
  !advanced_view_mode?
end

def prepare_for_viewing
  session[:viewing_param] = params[:mode] if params[:mode]
end
```

Also try not to repeat markup, but if you have completely separate views, it might be worth it to render different pages all together.

```
<div class="container" id="<%= advanced_view_mode? ? 'advanced' : 'basic' %>">

  This is common content

  <%= render 'advanced/partial' if advanced_view_mode? %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it out but I still have the same problem that when I click on a link to a different show-page (in this case a different product page) it switches back the view mode?

Comment: look at the parameters you are passing in with `<%= debug params %>` and make sure params[:mode] is in there on requests to change the viewing mode

Comment: :mode is set and in the debug params directly when the viewing mode is changed, but when I click on for example a link to /products/2 from /products/1, :mode is not there, should it?

Comment: no that sounds like its working. Try displaying the session data in the view and see if :viewing_param is in there

Comment: maybe located the problem, when I click on a link after a switch the :viewing_params is changed from "viewing_param"=>"1" to "viewing_param"=>"1.json"...?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - session variables wasn't persisted, I've used session variable a lot so I think it's the key thing to recreate the bug

However I've overcome this issue by using cookies instead of session

Just simply instead of

```
session[:viewing_param] = ..
if session[:viewing_param]
```

use

```
cookies[:viewing_param] = ..
if cookies[:viewing_param]
```

There are advanced options available

```
 cookies[:key] = {
   :value => 'dummy value',
   :expires => 1.month.from_now,
   :domain => 'domainname.com'
 }
```

Here is how to delete it:

```
   cookies.delete(:key, :domain => 'domain.com')
```

After switching to cookies I wasn't able to spot any non-persisting issues.