# Rails 2 - How to Use a Different Layout for an entire sub-site but still be able to use existing Controllers and Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using Rails version 2.3.14 and I am trying to figure out the best way to use a different layout for an entirely new section of my site but I can't think of the most efficient way to do it.

e.g. I have a CRM and everything is `localhost/controller/method` as normal but what I want to do is create a sub-section of my site named `portal`.

I considered creating a new app but I don't really want to do that since this sub section will be using existing controllers so I don't want to end up in the situation of having to remember to update both controllers to make sure their contents are identical as that will end up getting messy.

I read this answer [rails 3, how add a view that does not use same layout as rest of app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090084/rails-3-how-add-a-view-that-does-not-use-same-layout-as-rest-of-app) and it makes sense but I can't think how to apply that to my situation.

e.g. `http://localhost/` would show my existing login page and something like `localhost/portal` would show the login page for the new section but with a completely different layout but using the same models and controllers.

I'm new to rails so I might be over-thinking it or I might be barking up the wrong tree.

If it's possible I think the easiest way would be to somehow check the url for `portal` and set the layout based on the outcome of that check.

Comment: Do you have good reasons to use rails 2? It's ancient, you know. Which means that there are not many people who may remember answer to your question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the app was developed in that version and hasn't been updated.

Comment: Can you update it then? Anyway, good luck with this.

Comment: that would probably be a big job as some code might end up deprecated and gems would need updated along with the Ruby version aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the answer you posted, it makes sense, I just try to give you some real codes in your case.

You have a sub site, it means that your path of all pages in sub site will start with '/portal', right?

In your app/views/layout , you can add a layout named "portal_subsite.html.erb".

In your application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :get_layout

  private

  def get_layout
    if  request.path.start_with?('/portal')
      'portal_subsite'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
end
```

I have not a environment of Rails 2  now, but I think it should work, if you have any questions, please comment below.

Comment: thanks @Bigxiang, my existing url works (`localhost`) but if I go to `locahost/portal` I get the `Unknown Action` error but that makes sense since it thinks `portal` is a controller. Is there a way to tell the app to ignore the `portal` part and process requests as normal?

Comment: what do you want `locahost/portal` to go? Have you set the correct route in route.rb?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use existing controllers and models with a different layout. So both pages would do the same thing but look different. e.g. the `portal` section will use some existing controllers but the existing app will not use anything from the `portal` section. Hope that makes sense. I haven't set up the route yet, I will try it just now.

Comment: infact, I have just realised I don't know how to set up this route, e.g. something like `map.connect 'portal/:action/', :controller => ':action'` but that's not valid.

Comment: try `map.connect 'portal/:controller/:action/:id'` ? you can access such as "portal/users/login". This method just solves a part of problems you have, some routes need to be defined twice I think.

Comment: hmmm, still `Unknown Action`

Comment: What's your path you passed in the browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36520/discussion-between-bigxiang-and-martincarlin87)